# Regex for identifing a certificate uniquely

Tags: php, regex, certificate

I am trying to come up with regex that matches the value of "Key Container", but only if the issuer is CN=My_root_CA and the certificate is Non-root Certificate
All of the above should be fulfil to match the certificate uniquely, because there are several similar certificates

```
       ================ Certificate 3 ================
   Serial Number: 5471f66c066334ab48285398b0f24b7e
   Issuer: CN=My_Root_CA, O=Experian, OU=Hunter, L=Sofia, S=CA, C=BG
    NotBefore: 20/09/2016 15:48
    NotAfter: 20/09/2024 15:48
   Subject: CN=192.168.127.107
   Non-root Certificate
   Cert Hash(sha1): 46 92 41 60 56 36 32 fa bb 82 f2 45 0b 80 37 c4 28 15 e4 ca
     Key Container = 52668461-19b4-4fef-80d6-5982ff702c3b
     Unique container name: 0893f8f220ed765fabe249818ff664b9_bba0a089-1c2b-49c8-9f49-e4b211a91a55
     Provider = Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
   Encryption test passed
```

I have tried  this `CN=My_Root_CA((.|\n)*?)Non-root Certificate((.|\n)*?)Key Container =(.*\b)`

But this do not matches correctly if we have

```
  ================ Certificate 1 ================
   Serial Number: b4b81124ff17b6af4eb18053cd9fecd5
   Issuer: CN=My_Root_CA, O=Experian, OU=Hunter, L=Sofia, S=CA, C=BG
    NotBefore: 20/09/2016 15:48
    NotAfter: 20/09/2024 15:48
   Subject: CN=My_Root_CA, O=Experian, OU=Hunter, L=Sofia, S=CA, C=BG
   Signature matches Public Key
   Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
   Cert Hash(sha1): 8c 47 dd 5a 74 47 3a 74 e1 2a c4 de 6f 95 35 04 f6 2d d4 8a
     Key Container = 25ea8612-7fd3-4504-97f8-d9150e6bfd63
     Unique container name: 4e3f7aa1fb469fd4cb7b184d188059be_bba0a089-1c2b-49c8-9f49-e4b211a91a55
     Provider = Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
   Encryption test passed

   ================ Certificate 2 ================
   Serial Number: XXXXXXXX
   Issuer: CN=TEST TEST FIND Root
    NotBefore: 18/08/2015 16:16
    NotAfter: 18/09/2017 16:26
   Subject: CN=TEST CA
   CA Version: V9.0
   Certificate Template Name (Certificate Type): SubCA
   Non-root Certificate
   Template: SubCA
   Cert Hash(sha1): 55 1b 22 8c c9 eb 25 58 25 3f 00 67 a3 6e 68 b1 62 43 de 75
   No key provider information
   Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.
   Encryption test passed

   ================ Certificate 3 ================
   Serial Number: 5471f66c066334ab48285398b0f24b7e
   Issuer: CN=My_Root_CA, O=Experian, OU=Hunter, L=Sofia, S=CA, C=BG
    NotBefore: 20/09/2016 15:48
    NotAfter: 20/09/2024 15:48
   Subject: CN=192.168.127.107
   Non-root Certificate
   Cert Hash(sha1): 46 92 41 60 56 36 32 fa bb 82 f2 45 0b 80 37 c4 28 15 e4 ca
     Key Container = 52668461-19b4-4fef-80d6-5982ff702c3b
     Unique container name: 0893f8f220ed765fabe249818ff664b9_bba0a089-1c2b-49c8-9f49-e4b211a91a55
     Provider = Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
   Encryption test passed
```

Comment: Is it Java? Please share your current code. A regex will be either long or inefficient, but may be good enough.

Comment: it is ant. But the issue is easily visible in regex101                                   <!-- Get Key Container value -->   
      <propertyregex property="local.machine.keycontainer.withspaces"
      input="${local.machine.certutil.result}"
      regexp="CN=My_Root_CA((.|\n)*?)Non-root Certificate((.|\n)*?)Key Container =(.*\b)"
      select="\5"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
CN=My_Root_CA(?:(?!={4,})[\s\S])*?Non-root Certificate(?:(?!={4,})[\s\S])*?Key Container\s+=\s+(.*\b)
```

`(?:(?!={4,})[\s\S])*?` ->  won't go beyond four = signs.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sT0lO1/1)

Comment: Tempered greedy token with a lazy quantifier is not a good idea, but good enough. I'd unroll it to be more efficient.

Comment: inefficient? he clearly shows hit attempt.. You mean regex? THis works for now.. :-)

Comment: I do not mean if there is any attempt or not, just that the idea of a tempered greedy token is to restrict the part of the string  to match up to the next token the quickest way (the shortest path). Yes, sure, it should work at least at regex101.com.